# Unable build ABB YuMi Support

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, abb, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to the ROS systems and have come to a dead stop, can someone with experience assist.

System so far:

- Ubuntu VM 16.04.2 Kinetic
- ROS installed and builds
- ROS-I core builds
- gazebo works
- gazebo_ros_pkgs builds

cloned package from https://github.com/OrebroUniversity/yumi

When I build I get warnings and errors errors:

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:166 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'gazebo_ros' but neither
  'gazebo_ros_INCLUDE_DIRS' nor 'gazebo_ros_LIBRARIES' is defined.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:102 (_catkin_package)
  YuMi/gazebo_mimic/CMakeLists.txt:14 (catkin_package)

CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "abb_egm_interface"
  with any of the following names:

    abb_egm_interfaceConfig.cmake
    abb_egm_interface-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "abb_egm_interface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "abb_egm_interface_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "abb_egm_interface" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  YuMi/yumi_hw/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'abb_egm_interface'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "abb_egm_interface"
  with any of the following names:

    abb_egm_interfaceConfig.cmake
    abb_egm_interface-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "abb_egm_interface" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "abb_egm_interface_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "abb_egm_interface" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  YuMi/yumi_hw/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pbprobotics/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pbprobotics/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I am obviously missing something, can anyone help.

Bob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265655/unable-build-abb-yumi-support/) by [Bob Walton](https://answers.ros.org/users/31054/bob-walton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bob Walton](https://answers.ros.org/users/31054/bob-walton/) on 2017-07-06**:
rosdep check --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic
System dependencies have not been satisified:
ERROR[yumi_hw]: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [abb_rws_interface]
OS name    : ubuntu
OS version : xenial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latest version of that package depends on unreleased software (`abb_rws_interface`). It appears that the changes that introduced that dependency were merged into `master` by accident.

[21833bb1](https://github.com/OrebroUniversity/yumi/commit/21833bb1dd03fbc5e66666cc287224f73647c98f) reverts that, so `master` should build again.

See also [OrebroUniversity/yumi#15](https://github.com/OrebroUniversity/yumi/issues/15) for a related issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bob Walton](https://answers.ros.org/users/31054/bob-walton/) on 2017-07-09**:
Thanks for the feedback I can now build once the master was reverted.